# When using Capacitor external url navigation, the cookie in the header automatically drops in iOS

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have a website that has an onboarding (sign in) flow implemented, and upon successfully signed-in, I use the cookie in the header to navigate to the next rout to collect some user inputs prior completing the onboarding flow. Something I noticed was when using a server url defined in the **CapacitorConfig** file, completely works the entire flow without any issue(as shown bellow).

Inside my react project, inside the capacitor.config.js:

```
 "server": {
    "url": "https://someonboadingflow.net"
 }
```

However from my react project if I use it as bellow, it will take me to the initial rout where I could enter the user name and password, but then it wont take me to the next rout as it drops the cookie from the header. Wonder why I worked well on the 1st instance and not in the 2nd? **Whats the Difference ?**

```
  "server": {
    "allowNavigation": [
     "*.someonboadingflow.net",
    ]
  }
```

**I do not wants to purely load it as a server url** the fact after completing the onboarding phase I wants it to redirect back my app.

I know there is an open issue on properly patching cookies on iOS when it comes to capacitor ([link](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/1373#issuecomment-603308028)). But then wonder how it worked perfectly on my 1st instance and not in 2nd. **And what the best way to achieve my objective mentioned**. Amy help would much appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Since the cookie drops, maybe page loads not in WebView but in an external browser instead.

`*.someonboadingflow.net` means all subdomains (e.g. `https://subdomain.someonboadingflow.net`), but in the `server.url` you specified `https://someonboadingflow.net`.

Try to change `allowNavigation`:

```
  "server": {
    "allowNavigation": [
     "someonboadingflow.net",
    ]
  }
```